# Set variable to subset of array by condition in js

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am relatively new to JS and would like to find the best method to set one variable equal to a subset of another variable another based on a dynamic condition.

In the example below,

- `clickedCode` is a string that changes after each click event (all of the code below is within a click.event function).
- `features` is an array of features with 400 elements, each containing a `properties` object which in turn contains elements such as latitude, longitude, etc.
- `cities` is an empty array

  ```
        var clickedCode // dynamically changing string
        var cities = [];
        var features = map.queryRenderedFeatures({layers:['uni']});
  ```

for example, if I log some properties of the first `feature`, I will see:

```
var lon = features[0].properties.lon
var lat = features[0].properties.lat
var code = features[0].properties.code

console.log("" + lon + " " + lat + " " + code);
```

`4.7005 50.8798 EMPHID`

My objective is to subset `features` where `features[i].properties.code` is equal to `clickedCode` and then set `cities` equal to the resulting array so that roughly :

`cities = features where features[i].properties.code === clickedCode`

Any advice and explanation of structuring this in javascript would be helpful

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [Array.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

So in your case it would be something like this:

```
var cities = features.filter(function (feature){
    return feature.properties.code === clickedCode;
});
```

By simply passing a callback function to the filter (be sure that the function returns a truthy/falsy value, otherwise you could get undesired behavior).

Answer (score 1):

```
cities = features.filter(function(t)
         {
           return t.properties  &&  // check is not null
                  t.properties.code === clickedCode;
         });
```

the inner function runs for each element of array and returns a bool.

true => return element

false => filter it

Answer (score 0):

You can create a dictionary using `code` as key (I suppose it's unique)
Then access to the `clickedCode` by through the dictionary's key

```
var data = {}
features.each((feature) => {
  data[feature.properties.code] = properties
  cities.push(feature.properties.code)
})
console.log(data[clickedCode])
```

You also you don't need `cities` anymore, because

```
cities = Object.keys(data)
```

Comment: `code` is not unique - there are multiple elements in `features` with the same code as `clickedCode` = my goal is to filter only those and create an array out of them

Comment: so the @Goliadkin solution is the best